# How to read fields from JSON-LD to CSV?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, json-ld, ijson

I am trying to extract values from json ld to csv as they are in the file. There are a couple of issues I am facing.
1. The values being read for different fields are getting truncated in most of the cases. In the remaining cases the value of some other field is appearing in some other field.
2. I am also getting an error - 'Additional data' after some 4,000 lines.
The file is quite big(half a gb). I am attaching a shortened version of my code. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

The input file - I have shortened it and kept it here. There was no way of putting it here.

https://github.com/Architsi/json-ld-issue

I tried writing this script and I tried multiple online converters too

```
import csv, sys, math, operator, re, os, json, ijson
from pprint import pprint

filelist = []

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith(".json"):
        filelist.append(file)

for input in filelist:

    newCsv = []
    splitlist = input.split(".")
    output = splitlist[0] + '.csv'

    newFile = open(output, 'w', newline='') #wb for windows, else you'll see newlines added to csv

    # initialize csv writer
    writer = csv.writer(newFile)

    #Name of the columns
    header_row = ('Format', 'Description', 'Object', 'DataProvider')

    writer.writerow(header_row)

    with open(input, encoding="utf8") as json_file:

        data = ijson.items(json_file, 'item')

        #passing all the values through try except
        for s in data:

            source = s['_source']

            try:
                source_resource = source['sourceResource']
            except:
                print ("Warning: No source resource in record ID: " + id)

            try:
                data_provider = source['dataProvider'].encode()
            except:
                data_provider = "N/A"

            try:
                _object = source['object'].encode()
            except:
                _object = "N/A"

            try:
                descriptions = source_resource['description']
                string = ""
                for item in descriptions:
                    if len(descriptions) > 1:
                        description = item.encode() #+ " | "
                    else:
                        description = item.encode()
                    string = string + description
                description = string.encode()
            except:
                description = "N/A"


            created = ""
#writing it to csv
            write_tuple = ('format', description, _object, data_provider)

            writer.writerow(write_tuple)

    print ("File written to " + output)
    newFile.close()
```

The error that I am getting is this- raise common.JSONError('Additional Data')
Expected result is a csv file with all the columns and correct values

Comment: It seems very complicated. Did you consider using something like `pandas.read_json` to parse it?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @martineau Python 3.6

Comment: @AlexFish I dont think I have tried that yet.